# Is there any sufficient optimality conditions without constraints qualifications?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For a general nonlinear programming, is there any sufficient optimality conditions that do not imply constraints qualifications.

Comment: Are you referring to some specific constraint qualifications? In general "constraint qualification" just means "some property of the point and the constraints that guarantees optimality", so any optimality condition that we can actually *check* is a constraint qualification.

Comment: I am referring to a theorem I have found in the book "numerical optimization" that states the first order necessary conditions. One of the requirements are the LICQ. I am now trying to find optimality conditions without introducing these requirements. Here an example, I have a nonlinear programming involving 2 variables for which 3 constraints are active. In this way, the LICQ will never be hold. What can I do in that case.? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications) provides a list of some alternatives. If you have a specific example in mind, I can be more specific.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank for you answer. Yes I may give you a specific example but before doing so, let me just redefine my problem. In fact, I am not trying to solve an optimization problem but trying to construct a solution x* for a specific problem. To do this, I suppose given a value x* and I try to verify sufficient conditions. Here are a sample of problems I face: 1- I try to verify First Order necessary conditions, they are all satisfied as well as the LICQ, my question is: if the number of unknowns is equal to the number of active constraints, (see next comment plz)

Comment: should I verify the second order sufficient conditions? If so, the null space of the space formed by the gradient of active constraints will be empty. In this case, are first order conditions enough?